# Fragende Ankündigung: Doppelpunkt und/oder Fragezeichen?

Tags: punctuation

Ankündigungen, wie diese hier, und auch wie die folgende, werden mit einem Doppelpunkt abgeschlossen:

> Das Ergebnis der Untersuchung lautet: Der Täter war Linkshänder.

Fragesätze schließt man mit einem Fragezeichen ab:

> Womit schließt man Fragesätze ab?

**Aber wie ist das in Fällen wie bei dieser fragenden Ankündigung hier?:**

> Welches Zeichen ist zu setzen, wenn eine Ankündigung als Frage formuliert wird?

- Nur ein Doppelpunkt? - Dann fehlt das Fragezeichen am Ende der Frage.
- Nur ein Fragezeichen? - Dann fehlt der Doppelpunkt am Ende der Ankündigung.
- Beide Zeichen? - Ich habe das oben zur Demonstration zwar so gemacht, halte das aber für falsch.

---

### Edit:

Um Missverständnisse zu vermeiden:
Es geht um den **fett** hervorgehobenen Satz, der mit »Aber« beginnt, und den ich zum Zweck der Hervorhebung des Problems mit »**?:**« abgeschlossen habe. (Das Wort *hier* am Ende dieses Satzes bezieht sich auf den Satz in dem das Wort *hier* steht.)
Es geht nicht um die nachfolgende, gelb hinterlegte, Frage, die eine Listenauswahl ankündigt. Bei dieser Listenauswahl-Frage ist klar, dass sie nur ein Fragezeichen benötigt.

---

### Nachtrag:

(Reaktion auf einen [Kommentar](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/36402/fragende-ank%C3%BCndigung-doppelpunkt-und-oder-fragezeichen#comment89849_36404).)

Ich gebe ein weiteres Beispiel:

> Enthält der folgende Satz ein zweisilbiges Wort?: Der Täter war Linkshänder.

Hier ist zu beachten, dass es sich beim ersten Satz um eine geschlossene Frage handelt, also um eine Frage die mit »ja« oder »nein« zu beantworten ist. Der zweite Satz kann hier also keinesfalls als eine Liste mit nur einem Element interpretiert werden, denn es macht schlichtweg keinen Sinn, der geschlossenen Frage eine Liste folgen zu lassen, vor allem wenn in der Frage auch noch ausdrücklich von genau einem Satz die Rede ist.

Comment: Ich denke man könnte ein paar klarere Beispiele finden. Etwa: `Finden Sie das professionell?: Mein Chef ruft mich mitten in der Nacht an.` oder `Wie würden sie hier vorgehen?: Ein geparkter Wagen versperrt die Einfahrt.`

Comment: "Der Täter war Linkshänder. Enthält der vorhergende Satz ein zweisilbiges Wort?" Pragmatisch kann man durch Umstellungen der Gefahr entgehen, etwas falsch zu machen. :) Als Leser stört mich eine Satzzeichendopplung am meisten. Für die anderen Alternativen gibt es jeweils Begründungen - ich denke man kann beide gelten lassen. Leiten sollte man sich lassen von der Frage, was am besten verständlich ist. Mir würde aber keines der Satzzeichen fehlen. Ist aber nur meine Meinung.

Answer (score 10):

Laut Duden Band 9 – *Richtiges und gutes Deutsch* macht das Fragezeichen den Doppelpunkt überflüssig, wenn eine Frage gleichzeitig die Ankündigung einer Aufzählung in Form einer Liste ist.

> In welcher Stadt steht das abgebildete Gebäude?
>
> - Wien
> - Rom
> - Paris

Comment: Das zu wissen ist auch interessant (daher kein -1), aber nach Auswahlen aus Listen habe ich nicht gefragt (daher auch kein +1). Ich wollte wissen, wie das im Fall der fett hervorgehobenen Frage ist: **Wie ist das im folgenden Beispiel?:** Wie ist das, wenn die Frage gar keine Liste enthält?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast In deinem Beispiel hat die Liste halt nur ein Element.

Comment: @Robert: Wenn man unbedingt will, kann man mein erstes Beispiel tatsächlich so interpretieren. Daher habe ich im Nachtrag meiner Frage ein anderes Beispiel hinzugefügt, das diese Interpretation nicht zulässt.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ok, dann ist die implizierte Liste "ja" und "nein".

Comment: @Robert: Sorry, aber etwas, das gar nicht da steht, als Begründung dafür anzuführen ein Satzzeichen wegzulassen, ist schon sehr an den Haaren herbeigezogen.

Comment: @Robert Könnte so sein. Ich vermute es, wüsste es aber gern mit Gewissheit ;)

Answer (score 3):

Versuch einer Antwort:

1. Beide Satzzeichen (Fragezeichen und Doppelpunkt) zu setzen, kommt wohl nicht in Frage. Also wird man wohl auf eines verzichten müssen. Eine Kombination von Satzzeichen (ausser bei Klammern und Anführungszeichen) gibt es m.W. nur im Umfeld des Gedankenstrichs.
2. Die Regeln des Rechtschreibrats besagen: *Ein Fragezeichen beendet einen Ganzsatz, ein Doppelpunkt dient der Gliederung innerhalb des Ganzsatzes.* Deine Frage ist allerdings u.U. (je nach Betrachtungsweise) noch nicht zuende. In diesem Fall würde ich nach dem ersten Teilsatz kein Fragezeichen, sondern einen Doppelpunkt sehen wollen.

   > (a) Aber wie ist das in Fällen wie bei dieser fragenden Ankündigung hier:
   >   Welches Zeichen ist zu setzen, wenn eine Ankündigung als Frage formuliert wird?

Aber an sich täte es dann auch ein ganz normales Komma:

> (b) Aber wie ist das in Fällen wie bei dieser fragenden Ankündigung hier,
>   welches Zeichen ist zu setzen, wenn eine Ankündigung als Frage formuliert wird?

Dann besteht der Ganzsatz aus einer Aufzählung von zwei Fragen.

Wird die erste "Frage-Ankündigung" als Ganzsatz betrachtet, darf man nach Regel 83 der Rechtschreibregeln: *Zwischen zwei Ganzsätzen kann man zusätzlich zum Schlusszeichen einen Gedankenstrich setzen, um – ohne einen neuen Absatz zu beginnen – einen Wechsel deutlich zu machen.*"

> (c) Aber wie ist das in Fällen wie bei dieser fragenden Ankündigung hier? -
>   Welches Zeichen ist zu setzen, wenn eine Ankündigung als Frage formuliert wird?

Ich bin mir ziemlich sicher, dass alle drei Beispiele (a), (b) und (c) richtig sind. Die Auswahl bleibt allerdings dem Schreiber überlassen - Ob er die beiden Fragen als sich ergänzende Teilsätze eines Ganzsatzes oder als zwei für sich alleine stehende Ganzsätze betrachten will. Ich persönlich würde mich wohl für (b) oder (c) entscheiden.

Comment: Der Doppelpunkt dient nicht nur der Gliederung in Ganzsätzen. Siehe §81.2 der amtlichen Regeln, konkret meine ich die »Erklärungen«, insbesondere das letzte Beispiel: »*Beachten Sie bitte folgenden Hinweis: Infolge der anhaltenden Trockenheit besteht Waldbrandgefahr.*« Hier stehen zwei Ganzsätze hintereinander, wovon der erste den zweiten ankündigt. Meine Frage betrifft den Fall, dass der erste der beiden Ganzsätze ein Fragesatz ist.

Comment: Ein *Ganzsatz* ist mehr als nur ein im grammatischen Sinne vollständiger Satz mit Subjekt, Prädikat und Objekt, sondern eine semantisch in sich geschlossene Einheit - Daher ist das von dir genannte Beispiel **ein** Ganzsatz, nicht zwei.

Comment: ...und zwar genau *wegen* des Doppelpunktes.

Answer (score 3):

Ein Aussagesatz wird mit einem Punkt oder Ausrufungszeichen beendet und ein Fragesatz mit einem Fragezeichen.

Mit dem Doppelpunkt kündigt man an, dass etwas Weiterführendes
folgt (siehe amtliches Regelwerk der Deutschen Rechtschreibung, §81).
Dies betrifft:

1. wörtlich wiedergegebene Äußerungen oder Textstellen, wenn der
   Begleitsatz oder ein Teil von ihm vorausgeht
2. Aufzählungen, spezielle Angaben, Erklärungen oder dergleichen
3. Zusammenfassungen des vorher Gesagten oder Schlussfolgerungen
   aus diesem

Das bezieht sich aber alles auf Aussagesätze. Der Doppelpunkt im fettgeschriebenen Satz der Fragestellung oben ist also falsch. Man schreibt zwei getrennte Fragesätze, wobei beim Lesen des ersten klar wird, dass noch ein Nachfolgefragesatz folgt.

Answer (score 3):

Diese Frage ist eine Frage der Typographie, nicht unbedingt der Orthographie. Im Buch Detailtypographie von Friedrich Forssman und Ralf de Jong steht im Kapitel über *Satzzeichen und weitere Satzdetails* folgendes zu Ausrufe- und Fragezeichen:

> Na hoppla!: Wer sind Sie denn?
>
> Wer ich bin?! Professor Topolino!

Es ist also durchaus möglich einen Doppelpunkt nach einem Ausrufe- oder Fragezeichen zu setzen.

Answer (score 0):

Handelt es sich nicht einfach um zwei aufeinanderfolgende Fragen?

Beispiel:

> Was kann man gegen Moskitostiche tun? Reicht ein Netz wirklich aus?

Wäre das eine akzeptable Lösung Ihres Problems?

Übrigens: Sie halten zwar die Zeichenfolge Fragezeichen, Doppelpunkt in dem von Ihnen gemachten Beispiel für falsch, geben aber keinen Grund an, warum das falsch sein sollte.

Comment: Nein. Die Frage »Was kann man gegen Moskitostiche tun?« enthält keine Ankündigung. Sie könnte auch ganz alleine stehen, ohne die nachfolgende Frage.

Answer (score 0):

[Rechtschreibregel 19:](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/ausrufezeichen)

> Ein Ausrufezeichen steht auch bei Ausrufesätzen, die die Form einer
>   Frage haben.
>
> - Wie lange soll ich denn noch warten!
> - Ist denn das zu fassen!

Da das Fragezeichen hier also unterdrückt wird, würde ich für deinen Fall eine ähnliche Regel formulieren:

> Ein Doppelpunkt steht auch bei Ankündigungen, die die Form
>   einer Frage haben.

Dein letztes Beispiel würde demnach so aussehen:

> Enthält der folgende Satz ein zweisilbiges Wort: Der Täter war
>   Linkshänder.

Comment: Aus der Regel 19 könnte ich genauso gut ableiten: »*Ein Fragezeichen steht auch bei Fragen, die die Form einer Ankündigung haben.*« Vielleicht gibt es ja eine Hierarchie der Satzzeichen? Rufzeichen vor Fragezeichen vor Doppelpunkt? Einige andere Antworten, die hier gepostet wurden, vertreten zumindest implizit genau diese Standpunkt. Ich vermisse bei deiner Antwort die Begründung, warum die eine Auslegung richtig und die andere falsch sein soll. Genau danach habe ich nämlich gefragt.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Regel 19 gibt dem Ausrufezeichen gegenüber dem Fragezeichen den Vorrang. Da ich keine Regel kenne, die dem _Fragezeichen_ den Vorrang einräumt, ist Regel 19 für mich ein Argument, auch dem Doppelpunkt den Vorrang einzuräumen, wenn er mit einem Fragezeichen kollidiert.

Comment: Ich kenne in der Tat auch keine Regel, die dem Fragezeichen einen Vorrang gegenüber dem Doppelpunkt einräumt. Allerdings kenne ich auch keine umgekehrte Regel. Deine Interpretation beruht lediglich auf persönlichen Vorlieben, die nicht von allen geteilt werden. So vertritt z.B. Loong in seiner Antwort den Standpunkt, der Doppelpunkt wäre falsch, nur das Fragezeichen wäre richtig, und er liefert dafür auch einen Beleg (wenngleich ich diesen Beleg nicht für schlüssig halte). Dein einziger Beleg ist deine persönliche Meinung, und das ist mir leider zu wenig.