# Sind zwei oder mehr verschiedene Satzzeichen hintereinander erlaubt?

Tags: punctuation

In der Frage *[Fragende Ankündigung: Doppelpunkt und/oder Fragezeichen?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/36402/1487)* habe ich zur Demonstration meiner dort gestellten Frage folgenden Satz geschrieben (beachte die Satzzeichen am Ende):

> Aber wie ist das in Fällen wie bei dieser fragenden Ankündigung hier?:

Etwas weiter darunter habe ich geschrieben, dass ich selbst die kombinierte Verwendung von Fragezeichen und Doppelpunkt für falsch halte, und sie nur zur Hervorhebung des dort nachgefragten Sachverhalts so geschrieben habe.

In einem leider mittlerweile gelöschten Kommentar hat dann aber jemand gefragt (sinngemäßes Zitat):

> Wo steht denn, dass mehrere verschiedene Satzzeichen verboten sind?

Daraufhin habe ich ein wenig recherchiert, um die Quelle zu nennen, habe aber nichts gefunden, und mittlerweile wurde leider eben auch der besagte Kommentar entfernt.

Nach der erfolglosen Recherche ist mir nun aber selbst unklar, ob Zeichenfolgen wie »?:«, »!:«, »?!« und ähnliche erlaubt oder verboten sind.

Bedarf dafür besteht, und so hat man zur Verkürzung der Zeichenfolge »?!« bereits im Jahr 1962 das Zeichen »‽« erfunden, das man [Interrobang](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrobang) nennt (*Unicode Codeposition U+203D*). Dieses Zeichen gehört nicht zu den offiziell erlaubten Interpunktionszeichen, aber seine Existenz belegt, dass man es gerne als Ersatz für »?!« oder »!?« verwenden würde, was wiederum belegt, dass es Bedarf gibt, Rufzeichen und Fragezeichen hintereinander zu verwenden.

Meine oben verlinkte Frage zeigt auch, dass es Situationen gibt, in denen zumindest einige Autoren gerne die Folge »?:« oder »:?« verwenden würden.

---

Ich habe im Buch mit dem Titel

> **Komma, Punkt und alle anderen Satzzeichen**
>   Die neuen Regeln der Zeichensetzung mit umfangreicher Beispielsammlung

aus der Duden-Reihe des Brockhaus-Verlags in der 4. überarbeiteten Auflage aus dem Jahr 2002 (ISBN: 3-411-04914-6) nachgesehen, habe aber in den mehr als 200 Seiten dieses Buches kein Wort über die Verwendung von mehreren Satzzeichen hintereinander gefunden.

Mehrere Satzzeichen hintereinander werden in diesem Buch nur behandelt, wenn eines dieser Zeichen ein Anführungszeichen ist. Fälle wie »?!« oder »?:« werden dort in keinem Kapitel erwähnt. Das lässt mich zwar glauben, dass diese Möglichkeiten in der deutschen Sprache nicht vorgesehen sind, denn sonst hätte man sie in diesem Buch behandelt, andererseits ist die Nichtbehandlung in diesem Buch aber auch kein ausdrückliches Verbot solcher Zeichensatzkombinationen. Denn weder ist der Duden, oder ein beliebiges Buch aus der Dudenreihe, ein offiziell verbindliches Regelwerk, noch erhebt das genannte Buch den Anspruch, alle erlaubten Fälle der Zeichensetzung abzudecken.

Daher frage ich:

- Sind Kombinationen von zwei oder mehreren verschiedenen Satzzeichen in einem Text, der sich an alle offiziellen Regeln zur Schreibung deutscher Sprache hält, erlaubt oder verboten?
- Falls es ein Verbot gibt: Wo kann man es explizit nachlesen? Oder: Aus welchen ofiziellen Regeln kann dieses Verbot schlüssig abgeleitet werden?

Comment: Es ist gängig, Klammern, Anführungszeichen und auch Gedankenstriche mit anderen Satzzeichen zu kombinieren. Bei anderen eher nicht. Die nicht-Existenz eines Verbots heißt i.Ü. in der deutschen Grammatik nicht unbedingt, dass etwas erlaubt ist.

Comment: Für das Beispiel hättest du kein so kompliziertes und ungebräuchliches Zeichen suchen müssen: Ein simpler Strichpunkt hätte es wohl auch getan und ist auf jeder Tastatur vorhanden ;) Hier kann man auch gleich sehen, dass man zwei Satzzeichen  nicht notwendigerweise als "beides", sondern auch durchaus als "keins von beiden, sondern dazwischen" interpretieren kann - das gilt i.Ü auch für dein "‽"  (wobei ich allem, was Werbetexter erfinden, grundsätzlich mit Mißtrauen begegne...)

Comment: @tofro: Wer einen Strichpunkt verwendet, verwendet ihn nicht als Ersatz für die Kombination »,.«, sondern weil er ein Zeichen haben will, das stärker trennt als das Komma, aber schwächer als der Punkt. Wie du richtig geschrieben hast, steht der Strichpunkt in seiner Bedeutung zwischen Punkt und Komma. Mit einem Interrobang will man aber nicht eine Interpunktion setzten, die eine Bedeutung zwischen Fragezeichen und Rufzeichen hat, sondern ein Zeichen, das beides zugleich, jeweils im vollen Umfang bedeutet.

Comment: (Forts.) Selbst wenn es den Strichpunkt nicht gäbe, hätte niemand das Bedürfnis irgendwo Komma und Punkt direkt hintereinander zu schreiben. Man würde sich dann für genau eine der beiden Möglichkeiten entscheiden. Um solche Fälle geht es in meiner Frage aber nicht. Es geht ausdrücklich um Fälle, in denen man beide Zeichen in ihrer vollen Bedeutung brauchen würde, weil der Verzicht auf eines der beiden die Intention des Autors beschneiden würde. - Davon abgesehen geht es mir eben genau NICHT um einzelne Zeichen, egal ob Strichpunkt oder Interrobang. Damit wollte ich nur einen Bedarf belegen.

Comment: Das war doch genau, was ich meinte: Die Verwendung von zwei Satzzeichen ist kein bisschen besser als die eines einzigen, weil das eben mißverständlich, weil nicht gebräuchlich ist - Siehe Semikolon.

Comment: @tofro: Ok, dann habe ich dich falsch verstanden, tut mir leid. Aber gerade Missverständlichkeit, bzw. deren Vermeidung, ist im Bereich der Sprache nun wirklich kein Argument für oder gegen irgend etwas.

Comment: Das ist jetzt Humbug und hört sich so an, als ob Sprache prinzipell danach trachten würde, mißverständlich zu sein. Ich hege immer noch die Hoffnung, dass das Gegenteil der Fall ist...

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/338224/can-i-use-a-colon-and-a-question-mark-at-the-same-time

Comment: @tofro: Nein, ich unterstelle keine Absicht. Aber es ist nun mal so, dass unter allen Systemen, die zum Transport von Informationen verwendet werden, die natürliche Sprache jenes ist, das mit Abstand die meisten Widersprüche und Vieldeutigkeiten enthält.

Comment: Das ist nicht einfach (denn später wird er fragen: "Wo steht das denn?!").

Comment: @Takkat: Falls du mich meinst: Ich werde das nicht erst später fragen, ich habe diese Frage hier bereits ganz explizit gestellt. Ich zitiere aus dem letzten Absatz meiner Frage: »*Wo kann man es explizit nachlesen?*«

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: schon klar, ich meine damit, dass ich nur kommentieren aber nicht antworten kann, denn ich habe tatsächlich keine expliziten Regeln gefunden. Obiges Beispiel zeigt aber, dass 5 Satzzeichen hintereinander zumindest möglich sind.

Comment: @Takkat: Naja, Klammern, Gedankenstriche, Anführungszeichen und meinetwegen auch Schrägstriche haben ja einen Sonderstatus. Mir geht es eher um die "normalen" Satzzeichen: Punkt, Beistrich (Komma), Strichpunkt, Doppelpunkt, Rufzeichen (Ausrufezeichen) und Fragezeichen.

Comment: Auch wenn ich keine Regel dafür finde, würde ich kein „?:” setzen. Das Fragezeichen steht immer am Ende des Satzes und dieser endet am Doppelpunkt noch nicht. Also an deiner Stelle sollte meiner Ansicht nach nur ein „:” stehen und das „?” kannst du nach dem angekündigten Beispiel setzen, wenn du den Fragecharakter des Satzes unterstreichen möchtest.

Comment: @MatthiasWimmer Sehe ich genauso. Deshalb heißen **.**, **!** und **?** auch Satz*end*zeichen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In meinem Duden-Band »Richtiges und gutes Deutsch« von 1998 heißt es im Eintrag zum Fragezeichen:

> Nach einem Fragezeichen kann noch ein Ausrufezeichen stehen, wenn der
>   Fragesatz gleichzeitig als Ausrufesatz verstanden werden soll:
>
> - Auch du, mein Sohn?!
> - Warum denn nicht?!

Und im Online-Duden heißt es sowohl in [Regel 19](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/ausrufezeichen) als auch in [Regel 36](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/fragezeichen):

> Gelegentlich werden ein Fragezeichen und ein Ausrufezeichen gesetzt,
>   um einen Fragesatz gleichzeitig als Ausrufesatz zu kennzeichnen.
>
> - Was fällt dir denn ein?!

Comment: Oh, das überrascht mich jetzt. Aber das scheint nur für Fragezeichen und Rufzeichen (bzw. Ausrufezeichen, wie sie offenbar in Deutschland heißen) zu gelten. Gibt es auch etwas allgemeinere Aussagen, die auch die Kombination »?:« erlauben würden?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Allgemeinere Aussagen habe ich keine gefunden, auch nichts zum Spezialfall »?:«, weder ein Verbot noch eine Erlaubnis. Das Buch von 1998 enhält auch kein Stichwort »Satzzeichen«, was für Allgemeinaussagen ja der richtige Platz wäre.