# Wo gehört das Fragezeichen hin, wenn ein unvollständiger Satz nach der Frage folgt?

Tags: punctuation

In einer Mailkonversation hat jemand mir geschrieben:

"Gratulation zum Neuerwerb!"

Meine Antwort war, seitdem ich nicht wusste was er genau meinte, eine Frage:

> Danke! Aber welchen meinst du? Den Schlepper oder die Bohrmaschine?

Das sieht aber komisch aus. Der Satz nach dem ersten Fragezeichen ist ja unvollständig, und sollte wohl mit einem Kleinbuchstaben anfangen? Oder sollte das erste Fragezeichen durch ein Komma ersetzt werden?

Comment: Da nimmt man einen Doppelpunkt: *Aber welchen meinst du: Den Schlepper oder die Bohrmaschine?* Komma geht auch. Zwei Fragesätze sind natürlich auch erlaubt, es sieht halt nur "komisch" aus.

Comment: Also doch ein großer Buchstabe in "Den" nach dem Doppelpunkt?

Comment: Nach dem Doppelpunkt folgt im Deutschen immer ein Großbuchstabe.

Comment: @Janka: Siehe [Duden, Doppelpunkt](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/doppelpunkt), Regel *D 34*, zweites Beispiel: »**Familienstand: verheiratet**«. Siehe auch [online lernen](http://www.online-lernen.levrai.de/deutsch-uebungen/rechtschreibung_5_7/25_deutsch_ueben_satzzeichen/62_uebung_grossschreibung_nach_doppelpunkt.htm), Abschnitt »Nach dem Doppelpunkt schreibt man klein, wenn kein ganzer Satz folgt.« Oder auch [neue Rechtschreibung](http://www.neue-rechtschreibung.net/2009/08/14/nach-doppelpunkt-gros-oder-klein/): »**Ende: gegen 20 Uhr.**«

Comment: @Bea: Nein, nicht groß, sondern klein, also: *»Aber welchen meinst du: **d**en Schlepper oder die Bohrmaschine?«* Begründung: Der Teil *»den Schlepper oder die Bohrmaschine«* enthält kein Verb, und ist daher kein ganzer Satz, und wenn dieser Teil auf einen Doppelpunkt, ist er folglich kleinzuschreiben.

Comment: Ein Komittee hat das beschlossen. Ich warte noch darauf, dass auch dies rückabgewickelt wird.

Comment: @Janka Das war auch schon bei der alten Rechtschreibung vor 1996 so, siehe alte Regel 79: „… Klein schreibt man dagegen nach einem Doppelpunkt, der vor einer angekündigten Aufzählung, einem angekündigten Satzstück oder vor einer Zusammenfassung oder Folgerung steht.“

Comment: Related: [Fragende Ankündigung: Doppelpunkt und/oder Fragezeichen?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/36402/9551)

Comment: [Hier gilt die amtliche Regel §54](http://canoo.net/services/GermanSpelling/Amtlich/GrossKlein/pgf53-54.html#pgf54) nur, wenn nach dem Doppelpunkt ein ganzsatzartiges Gebilde folgt.